# How to scan a specific String with Regular Expression?

Tags: java, string

I have a string and I want to check if it includes some specific characters. If it includes this characters, an error message muste be occured.

I have an idea and plan to work with the classes "Pattern" and "Matcher":

```
public boolean sourceIncludesValidCharacters(String sourceToScan, String searchCharacter) {

    boolean sourceIncludesValidCharacters = true;

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(sourceToScan)) {
        sourceIncludesValidCharacters = false;
    } else {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchCharacter);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceToScan);
        sourceIncludesValidCharacters = !matcher.find();
    }
    return sourceIncludesValidCharacters;
}
```

Now I need a kind of regular expression to check my string (or in other words the parameter "sourceToScan". The Regular Expression muste be filtered signs like `[]/{}%$§` and so on...

How can I implemented this solution in the example?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), no need for regex here:

```
String[] mySpecialChars = ....;   //I advise to make it constant
for(String special : mySpecialChars) {
   if(myStr.contains(special)) {
      //error
   }
}
```

---

You can put this inside a method to have a clearer solution:

```
private boolean containsSpecialChars(String myStr) {
    String[] mySpecialChars = ....; 
    for(String special : mySpecialChars) {
       if(myStr.contains(special)) {
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Note**: Regex is suitable to use in cases where you have some *pattern*. In this case, you simply want to check if some char exists in the String, in not any special/specific pattern. That's why using regex is less suitable here.

Comment: But this solution is a little bit unbeautiful. I would like to work with the classes Pattern and Matcher, so i don´t need any kind of loop for this solution

Comment: [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) was invented to be used in situation like this one. I don't think it's not beautiful, you can write this in a method `containsSpecialChars` and you're done.

Comment: Ok, but how i must initialse the Array String[] mySpecialChars?

Comment: @Marwief I suggest you to make it final and put there all special chars, once.

Comment: I have a question again. How is it possible to ceate a String array with some special characters like Ö, ä, Ü and so on. That is very important for me since UTF 8 encoding. Now this solution with a String Array directly in java code causes a error

Comment: @Marwief it would only cause an error if you have incorrect encoding settings in your java source code editor. Java has no problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate about the cleanliness, comparison of string.contains() method and regular expression method, with String.contains():

```
String specialChars[] = {"]", "["};

for (String char: specialChars) {
    if (targetString.contains(char)) {
         return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

and with regular expression

```
String specialCharsPattern = ".*[\\]\\[].*";

if (targetString.matches(specialCharsPattern)) {
     return false;
}
return true;
```

Examples:

```
class Match {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "test[me";
        System.out.println(str + ": " + containsSpecialCharsRegEx(str));
        System.out.println(str + ": " + containsSpecialCharsContains(str));
    }
    public static boolean containsSpecialCharsRegEx(String targetString) {
        final String specialCharsPattern = ".*[\\]\\[].*"; // for the symbols [ and ] in this example

        if (targetString.matches(specialCharsPattern)) {
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static boolean containsSpecialCharsContains(String targetString) {
        final String[] specialCharsArr = {"]", "["}; // for the symbols [ and ] in this example

        for (String specialChar: specialCharsArr) {
            if (targetString.contains(specialChar)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I certainly think with .contains it is cleaner and more understandable.